# Consulta SQL con dos tablas, filtrado muy específico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo dos tablas en SQL Server conformadas de las siguiente manera:

```
1) Clientes:
   - IdCLiente
   - Nombre
2) Vehiculos:
   - idVehiculo
   - idCliente
   - Marca
   - Color
```

Necesito que **solo** traiga clientes si **TODOS** sus vehículos son de color rojo (por ejemplo), es decir, si tengo un cliente por ejemplo:

| IdCLiente | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Raul Peña |

Que tiene los vehículos:

| idVehiculo | idCliente | Marca | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | Ford Fiesta | Rojo |
| 002 | 001 | Citroen C4 | Azul |

Este cliente ya no puede salir en los resultados porque tiene un vehículo que no es rojo.

¿Alguna idea de como hacer esta consulta?

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Ahora se lee mas claro!

Comment: No hay de que, puedes echar un ojo a: [Formatos de texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), te ayudara en las proximas veces. Tambien te recominedo leer tanto la documentacion de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), como la de [ejemplos mínimos, completos y verificables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), esto te ayudara a que tus preguntas sean mas faciles de enteder y pueda recibir ayuda. Un saludo y bienvenido a la comunidad :)

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción para obtener lo que deseas es usar funciones de agregado y la clausula `HAVING`.

Dejo dos ejemplos de como hacerlo.

```
SELECT   c.IdCLiente,
         c.Nombre
FROM     Clientes  c
JOIN     Vehiculos v ON c.IdCliente = v.IdCliente
GROUP BY c.IdCLiente,
         c.Nombre
HAVING MAX( Color) = 'Rojo'
AND    MIN( Color) = 'Rojo';


SELECT   c.IdCLiente,
         c.Nombre
FROM     Clientes  c
JOIN     Vehiculos v ON c.IdCliente = v.IdCliente
GROUP BY c.IdCLiente,
         c.Nombre
HAVING MAX( Color)            = 'Rojo'
AND    COUNT( DISTINCT Color) = 1;
```

Comment: Muy interesante podrías explicar como funciona el having max con textos ?

Comment: En texto, ordena similar a como lo haría un diccionario, pero integrando todos los caracteres disponibles. MAX() muestra lo que quedaría al final (como z) y MIN() lo que quedaría al inicio (como a). El orden lo determina la intercalación (COLLATION en inglés) de la columna.

Comment: Excelente gracias ,  crees que solo con AVG sea suficiente si es que lo admite ?

Comment: No lo admite. No sé cual sería tu lógica para un promedio de cadenas de texto. ¿Qué esperarías que fuera el promedio entre `rojo` y `azul`?

Comment: Ah ok , no disculpa lo pense mal , claro con AVG no llegaría a ninguna solución .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CLI.* 
FROM tablaClientes CLI 
JOIN tablaCoches C ON CLI.idCliente = C.idCliente 
WHERE CLI.idCliente NOT IN (SELECT c2.idCliente 
                            FROM tablaCoches c2 
                            WHERE c2.color = 'rojo');
```

La explicación es la siguiente:

Recoges todos los clientes que tengan un coche, menos aquellos que que tengan un coche de color rojo.

La subconsulta devuelve los IDs de aquellos clientes que tengan algún coche rojo. Y en la consulta de fuera dices que no te traiga los IDs de cliente que se encuentren en la lista anterior.